# How to merge 2 batteries socketof 6v each

Tags: battery

i want to merge 2 batteries socket of 4 AA 1.5v batteries , how can combine them to have 12v ?
[image]

Comment: Connect the + of A to the - of B. The + of B and - of A are 12V.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put them in serie. One red cable to another black cable. Glue the cases back to back.

Don't get confused by the clamps; I only used them for keeping things in place. Oh, my cases are for 3 batteries, but the procedure is aplicable to 4 batteries cases also.

[image]

Comment: Well , it makes some smoke

Comment: i was connecting red at black and other red at black then  i was measuring , i got some smoke:))

Comment: but i'm good now , ty

Comment: @RaduMihai - Please, for your own safety, step away from the electronics and find a website where you can learn some basics, before you injure yourself.